# Start Tor browser in Unity without grabbing focus

Tags: x11, firefox, window-management, unity, focus

I want to start Tor browser in background mode, i.e. I want to open a browser window but I want my terminal to keep the focus. I tried some solutions but they did not work. For instance:

```
nohup torbrowser --allow-remote
```

or

```
torbrowser &
```

I am using Ubuntu Unity 16.04.

Answer (score 0):

You can check `xdotool`.
This example will immediatly give back focus to your terminal window whenever it get lost:

```
xdotool getwindowfocus behave %1 blur windowfocus & xdotoolpid=$!
```

To stop this, `kill $xdotoolpid`

it is a chain of commands.

- `getwindowfocus` stores the window id of current active window (your terminal) on a window stack.
- `behave` reads the first entry from window stack (`%1`) and waits for event `blur` (=loosing focus).
- Whenever focus gets lost, `behave` executes command `windowfocus` to give focus back to `%1` (= your terminal window).

Other way around, it is possible to create an xdottool command that looks for tor browser window, but that could be a bit more complicated as it has to identify tor browser window and it is not already present.

(By the way, I suppose you want to use tor, not torbrowser itself. You can run tor as a system daemon without firefox, package `tor` in Ubuntu.)

Answer (score -2):

You are searching for [Selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/).

Comment: Does Selenium has Tor Browser features?

Comment: Tor browser is firefox with some default installed extensions.

Comment: Selenium integration in Firefox relies on a "Firefox WebDriver" plugin. While Tor browser is indeed based on firefox, the extension and configuration of the browser has been carefully chosen to withstand deanonymization attacks based on browser features. [Installing additional plugins of addons to Tor Browser is discouraged](https://www.torproject.org/download/download.html.en#Warning) as they may be used to deanonymize the user.

Comment: I agree with ThomasNyman